# Spring Batch Admin: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.jdbc.driver' in string value "${batch.jdbc.driver}"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to integrate spring batch with spring batch admin. But am getting this error `Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.jdbc.driver' in string value "${batch.jdbc.driver}"` Please help.Thanks.

```
enter code hereorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/dimakatso.bopape/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/82b20b57e2c2e2d910d7b2c37bf58c6976071f1/spring-batch-admin-manager-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/data-source-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.jdbc.driver' in string value "${batch.jdbc.driver}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.jdbc.driver' in string value "${batch.jdbc.driver}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
at za.co.momentum.retail.minion.batch.MinionBatchApplication.main(MinionBatchApplication.java:21)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'batch.jdbc.driver' in string value "${batch.jdbc.driver}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
    ... 13 common frames omitted

**resources/batch-db2.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql: false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: false

database.minion.url=jdbc:db2://***
database.minion.username=***
database.minion.password=***
database.minion.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

**resources/application.properties**

```
server.port=8091
-DENVIRONMENT=db2
```

**main class**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={ PersistenceConfig.class })
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class, MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableBatchAdmin
public class MinionBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MinionBatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Data source config**

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfig {

  @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database.minion")
    public DataSource minionDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
    }}
```

Comment: While starting the server are you able to see the properties in your console ?

Comment: I never used spring-boot batch but i have experience in spring-boot application..Instead of "-DENVIRONMENT=db2" set "-DENVIRONMENT=batch-db2"

Comment: I am not sure if your application.properties file will be picked up by spring before batch-db2.properties. One way to make sure of that is add a file named "bootstrap.yml" inside src/main/resources. bootstrap.yml will be loaded before any application properties file.add content in the file as following: ENVIRONMENT: db2

Comment: @VelNaga,  "-DENVIRONMENT=batch-db2" does not work also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your using spring batch admin it is important to override the files of spring batch admin provides.(Please find the image for configuration setup)
and then your properties file should look like this
[image]

```
 # Placeholders batch.*
#    for MySQL:
batch.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx
batch.jdbc.user=root
batch.jdbc.password=root
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=true
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=SELECT 1
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
batch.drop.script=classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql
batch.business.schema.script=classpath:business-schema-mysql.sql
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer

# Non-platform dependent settings that you might like to change
 batch.data.source.init=false
```

I think in your case "driver class" property name is different.

Comment: Won't 'batch.drop.script=classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql,,drop existing tables', I am using existing database which i don't wanna drop tables

Comment: in that case remove the "batch.drop.script" property. What ever properties you want to override mention those, rest you remove it.

Comment: it works, apparently "batch.data.source.init=false" prevent it from dropping the tables :)